# Wrapping C++ operator() with Python Boost

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have an operator

```
class A {
public:
    double operator()(double x)const{return eval(x);} 
    double eval(double x)const; 
};
```

How can I expose  `operator()` using Python Boost?

Comment: I have tried     .def( "__getitem__", &ParametricCurve::operator(), boost::python::arg( "eval" ),     boost::python::return_internal_reference<>() ) and also  .def(float_(self)) and tried to call the operator from a function so that i would not cover it and nothing worked. reason being I think i don't understand this. My apologies since I am quiet new to C++ as well as Python

Comment: I also tried this .def(self(), &A::operator()). The ParametricCurve in the previous comment is the class A which I tried to simplify while I wrote a question.

Comment: *while framing this question to be posted at stackoverflow in shortParametricCurve = class A . Sorry for the typo and this correction.

Comment: @user665903 hi! btw: you don't have to squeese your additions in comments, you can edit your original question (makes it easier to read your additions)

Comment: True that I just noticed it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class A
{
    public:
        double operator()( double x ) const { return eval(x); } 
        double eval( double x ) const { return x; } 
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    class_<A>("my_module")
        .def("__call__", &A::operator() )
    ;
}
```

Now in python shell:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_module
>>> x = my_module.my_module()
>>> x(5)
5.0
>>>
```

Comment: This gives me a segmentation fault and python crashes. eval does not return x but is a function that evaluates a function like this double ParametricCurve::eval(double x)const
{
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; (v[i] <= x) && (v[i] != FLT_MAX); i+=2)
    ;

  //if x is out of bounds approximate according to last values
  if (i == 0)
    i+=2;
  else if (v[i] == FLT_MAX)
    i-=2;
  
  //the evaluation of the function
  return v[i-1] + (v[i+1] - v[i-1])*((x - v[i-2]) / (v[i] - v[i-2]));

}

Comment: First, try to run the program without using python shenanigans. Does it work? Try to get the backtrace using "gdb" to pin point the seg-fault cause. My guess is, "i" is getting out of bound.

Comment: ok I ran the code in gdb and then it crashed at for (i = 0; (v[i] <= x) && (v[i] != FLT_MAX); i+=2) so like u said 'i' probably went out of bounds. but this does not happen when the wrapper is not used. I am not the author of the c++ code and it is a part of a bigger code. So i.e. the code works without the python wrapper and when I invoke the wrapper and in python it crashes. Actually there is a segmentation fault in python and implementing a standalone version in c++ would be also satisfying a lot of dependencies and other issues to invoke operator(). However the whole code works fine.